# jquery message box reserved area bug

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm working with a jQuery message box like [this](http://codepen.io/petebot/pen/CpKzI/). I would like to use this in my web application, but still I'm encountering one problem. This area of whole popup should be reserved. If you see this link you found if popup in closed conditions then when you move the cursor to the bottom then it's become handy cursor. This shows one bug.

However all I want to do is to make one jQuery notification box (just like our stack overflow) that list messages and when it goes closed no fixed area reservation problem.

Anyone know of a good plugin for this?

Could any one have solution for this ???

Comment: You can use toggle() with the ul #notificationMenu function in jquery for simply showing or hiding the notification box instead of toggling the class as "open".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that the message box never was hidden per se, it just had an `opacity` value of 0, thus not visible but still taking place. What you need to do is change its `display` property value, just like StackOverflow does on its message box.

**1.** Remove these two lines from `.notifications`:

```
transition: .2s;
opacity:0;
```

**2.** Add this line to `.notifications` (if you want the message box to be hiddne by default):

```
display:none;
```

**3.** Change the jQuery code to:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".notificationicon").click(function () {
   
    $("#notificationMenu").fadeToggle(200);
    
  });
});
```

**[codePen demo.](http://codepen.io/DanielLisik/pen/KgHaA)**

### Customization

If you want to customize the easing you can change `fadeToggle(200);` to `fadeToggle(200, 'EASING-TYPE');` where `EASING-TYPE` is a string value indicating which function to use for the transition (default is *swing* but can also be *linear*).

Comment: can u customize it's foundation style sheet for only this control. see this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23863668/how-to-omit-style-sheet-to-apply-style-to-other-web-page).

Comment: @Shal  did you add `display:none;` to `.notifications`? That should solve the problem with the dialog being open.

Comment: thanks so much can u see my another question that was i link out to u.